# iOS call logout webservice in the Background after 5 min

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I just want to know how to call a logout web method if the app is in background for 5 minutes. I have already used expiration handler:- beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:, but I am getting only 180 seconds in the background by using backgroundTimeRemaining property. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(yourMethod) withObject:Nil afterDelay:5.0/*enter desired time*/];
```

Comment: Yes Ashu i have used that code already but the problem is that after 5 minutes code is not executed because only 2minutes are allowed to perform task.